# Removing scientific notation format from character column type

Tags: r, scientific-notation

I have an issue where I have a column in a dataframe that is a character type as there is text in it so I cannot force it to be numeric. But I also have values that show up as scientific notation that I would like to convert and remove the scientific notation.

In the data assume there is an unknown amount of these values that need to be converted. How best can I remove the scientific notation from this type of data?

Example data:

```
vector <- c("HMM","5.8779396207367296E+17","GOLF","3191963","355534317","8.837971002284400E+16")
exampledf <- as.data.frame(vector)
```

what I would like it to look like:

```
vector <- c("HMM","587793962073672960","GOLF","3191963","355534317","80837971002284400")
```

Comment: In a number like `5.8779E17` how else would you write it without the scientific notation?

Comment: `as.numeric(vector)` correctly interprets all except HMM/GOLF in your `vector`, so the presence of the scientific notation is not blocking you. If you don't want it printed on the console, see [`?options`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/options.html) for `'scipen'`.

Comment: @r2evans I want to retain the text values though and not get rid of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `type.convert`:

```r
as.character(type.convert(as.list(vector), as.is = TRUE))
#[1] "HMM" "587793962073672960" "GOLF" "3191963" "355534317" "88379710022844000"
```